# Karate v1.4.0 - Multipart not working when executed from jar file

Tags: testing, cucumber, karate

I have a feature where I send a request with a multipart file using this line:

```
And multipart file csvFile = {read: '#(filePath)', contentType:'multipart/form-data'}
```

This is working perfectly with the Karate v1.4.0 from my local eclipse but when I compile as jar file and execute with "java -jar" command, the test is not working, it's sending the request with the file but the server is saying the multi-part is not right.

When I try the same with Karate v1.3.1 everything works perfectly, it seems something related with the version 1.4.0.

Has someone the same problem with multipart with the latest version?

INFO:

### Log when it works v1.4.0 from eclipse:

[image]

### Log when it doesn't work from jar file:

- See strange **line 10** where the filename is not set by karate
- See strange  **line 25** where karate set content-type: applicattion/jon??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the real reason but I solved it, adding to the multipart command a 'filename' attribute:

```
And multipart file csvFile = {read: '#(filePath)', contentType:'multipart/form-data', filename: '#(fileName)'}
```

It's strange because following the documentation (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multipart-file) the "filename" attribute is optional. Maybe it's a workaround to solve the problem in the v.1.4.0

I don't know if this bug is going to be resolved on karate next version or otherwise the karate doc must be changed.

Comment: maybe it is not optional for your server so not really a karate issue. please note that you can mark this answer as `accepted` now, it helps others

Comment: But with Karate v1.3.1 it woks without the 'filename' attribute, it seems something related with the version 1.4.0

Comment: okay, I'm not sure to be honest. I'll see if others report this, because I don't think this has come up before. any investigations into the source code by others is welcome